# Why is SpannableString equality defined as it is?

Tags: android, spannablestring

Consider the following test:

```
    @Test
    fun test() {
        val s1 = SpannableString("Test")
        val s2 = SpannableString("Test")
        s1.setSpan(StyleSpan(BOLD), 0, s1.length, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
        s2.setSpan(StyleSpan(BOLD), 0, s2.length, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)

        assertEquals(s1, s2)
    }
```

Should it succeed or fail?

My assumption was that it should succeed, but it fails (scratches head). When looking at the implementation of the `SpannableStringInternal` we see that the function compares each span with its counterpart (assuming we have equal number of spans).

```
 // Same as SpannableStringBuilder
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Spanned &&
                toString().equals(o.toString())) {
            final Spanned other = (Spanned) o;
            // Check span data
            final Object[] otherSpans = other.getSpans(0, other.length(), Object.class);
            final Object[] thisSpans = getSpans(0, length(), Object.class);
            if (mSpanCount == otherSpans.length) {
                for (int i = 0; i < mSpanCount; ++i) {
                    final Object thisSpan = thisSpans[i];
                    final Object otherSpan = otherSpans[i];
                    if (thisSpan == this) {
                        if (other != otherSpan ||
                                getSpanStart(thisSpan) != other.getSpanStart(otherSpan) ||
                                getSpanEnd(thisSpan) != other.getSpanEnd(otherSpan) ||
                                getSpanFlags(thisSpan) != other.getSpanFlags(otherSpan)) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    } else if (!thisSpan.equals(otherSpan) ||
                            getSpanStart(thisSpan) != other.getSpanStart(otherSpan) ||
                            getSpanEnd(thisSpan) != other.getSpanEnd(otherSpan) ||
                            getSpanFlags(thisSpan) != other.getSpanFlags(otherSpan)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The first condition in the `else if` compares the Span objects for equality and the style spans (although encoding the same data, and being the same type) are not equal, because it seems the `StyleSpan` does not overwrite equals.

Is there a specific reason why these two are not considered equal, or is it a bug in Android?